# Changing TTPhotoView Size

Tags: iphone, objective-c, three20

How do I change the size of TTPhotoView as it shows up in full screen by default. My user interface design requires me to decrease the size of TTPhotoView, probably to one-third of the screen size? So, is there anyway to achieve this? Is there any method in particular that I should override?

Answer (score 0):

The inheritance chain looks like:

```
TTPhotoView : TTImageView : TTView : UIView
```

So you should be able to adjust it's `frame` property, just like you would for a `UIView`, no?

```
TTPhotoView *photoView = [[TTPhotoView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,width,height)];
[self.view addSubview:photoView];
[photoView release];
```

Or something like that?

Comment: It doesn't work. I had tried overriding imageViewDidLoad method. But still the same result.